# CSP - worker-src blob security

Tags: security, content-security-policy

Is it safe using "blob" for "worker-src" in CSP or is there a security drawback? Couldn't anyone start a worker then by passing a blob from any website?

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#source-list-guid-matching, which says: *“allowing "blob:" or "filesystem:" URLs is equivalent to unsafe-eval”*. In other words, it’s not safe. That’s the reason why you need to explicitly specify "blob:" rather than it automatically being allowed by "self". The intent is that the act of needing to explicitly add "blob:" should make you stop and consider the possible risks involved. For some further context, see the commit comment at https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/commit/0f497cbe6f28dc9698fa4dc04a91b407278f8735